# Counting rows and saving the result in array (map) in Talend Open Studio

Tags: java, arrays, talend

I have a job in Talend Open Studio. It supposed to be counting filtered input rows and storing it in adequate variable. The input file is csv. Later I use tMap to take only rows from selected day:

[image: tMap]

And then I'm stuck. I just need an array (or array map?) with 24hrs (values 0-23) and increment them everytime the time matches.

How do I implement an array in Talend which I can use inside tMap (I can use third party library)? Or is there some other way of doing that? I want to output those variables values to csv.

Comment: why is this tagged java? (Is it java? I am not sure whether it could be related to java...)

Comment: because talend is build on eclipse, so I figured out the problem can be related to it. it's my first question here, should I delete the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, you want to sum all columns which do have a specific hour value. You could use a combination of *tMap* and *tAggregateRow*.

First, you would define a tMap with 24 columns on the right side. Row for row, this would only be filled if a condition is met, e.g.

```
TalendDate.getPartOfDate("HOUR",row1.Time_Stamp) == 0
```

into *columnHour0*,

```
TalendDate.getPartOfDate("HOUR",row1.Time_Stamp) == 1
```

into *columnHour1* etc. up to *columnHour23*.

Now connect the *tAggregateRow* and sum every hour column in the "Operations" box. This should result in only one row with all the counted hour entries.

Comment: I used tAgreggate row and it's funtions to output the hours user is active (I used also tMap to extract date from Time_Stamp. I got stuck in workflow and I forgot to check stackoverflow. But your response is really helpful. In the end I skipped using variables at all.
Anyway, thank you for the answer! I learned from it.

Comment: No problem. For others to find the most helpful answer faster, you could mark one as correct answer to this question and maybe upvote some answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write a user defined function and call it in tmap.. something like below

```
public static String loop_cntr(Int cntr){

String ARR = "" ;
for(int i=0;i<cntr;i++){
<your logic to build the array>
ARR = ARR + cntr (something like this)
}
return ARR
)
```

now you can use this function in tMap like loop_cntr(20)

I am assuming that you know how to write custom function Code-->Routines.
Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: I can't Java well. Actually I'm learning it along with Talend. I heard about the solution your mentioned though. Thank you for the answer and sorry for my delayed response. I used tAgreggate row and it's funtions to output the hours user is active (i used also tMap to extract date from Time_Stamp.

Answer (score -1):

do you know the components tflowmeter and tflowmetercatcher ?

Comment: Should be a comment!

Comment: I don't have enoug reputation to add a comment when i'm not on the thread.

Comment: Hey. I tried it, but it was confusion since flowmeter and flowmetercatcher are used mainly in debugging. I read some tutorials but I didn't know how to use it. Anyway thanks for suggestion.